# showing no output for the codility algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7

I am stuck with the following codility problem:

> A small frog wants to get to the other side of a river. The frog is
>   currently located at position 0, and wants to get to position X.
>   Leaves fall from a tree onto the surface of the river.
>
> You are given a non-empty zero-indexed array A consisting of N
>   integers representing the falling leaves. A[K] represents the position
>   where one leaf falls at time K, measured in seconds.
>
> The goal is to find the earliest time when the frog can jump to the
>   other side of the river. The frog can cross only when leaves appear at
>   every position across the river from 1 to X. You may assume that the
>   speed of the current in the river is negligibly small, i.e. the leaves
>   do not change their positions once they fall in the river.
>
> For example, you are given integer X = 5 and array A such that:
>
> A[0] = 1   A[1](https://codility.com/c/intro/demoNU3BN3-YC9) = 3   A[2] = 1   A[3] = 4   A[4] = 2   A[5] = 3
>   A[6] = 5   A[7] = 4 In second 6, a leaf falls into position 5. This is
>   the earliest time when leaves appear in every position across the
>   river.
>
> The code that I tried is:

```
def solution(X, A):
    for i in range(len(A)):       
        if A[i] == X:
            L1 =  A[i:]         
            for j in L1:
                count = 0
                if (j < X and j not in A[:i]):
                    count += 1
                    return i+count
                else:    
                    return i
X = raw_input()
A = map(int, raw_input().split())
print solution(X,A)
```

you can check the full question description [here](https://codility.com/c/intro/demoNU3BN3-YC9) 
The code is working only for some cases. I am quite new to python. Please let me know where I am doing the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

```
X = raw_input()
```

`raw_input` returns a string. A string never compares equal to an integer, so `if A[i] == X:` will never evaluate to True. Convert X to an integer before calling `solution`.

```
X = int(raw_input())
```

Now your code will produce output:

```
5
1 3 1 4 2 3 5 7
6
```

(... Although I haven't checked to see if it produces the *correct* output. That would best be saved for a separate question.)

Comment: Now its printing the output for simple case as above. However, if we define A = [1, 5, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7] and X=5. I am stlll getting the output as the index 1, not 4